How do i reference figures in agrid with Typst
I want to reference each figure in this grid individually but it won't let me
#figure(
    grid(
  columns: 2,
   grid.cell(
    figure(
    image("Pictures/PowerGeo.png", width:90%),
    caption: [Arithmetic operations],
  )
  ),
  grid.cell(
    figure(
    image("Pictures/PowerMath.png", width:90%),
    caption: [Geometric operations]
  )
  ),
),
)<power>

i can reference the entire figure using the @power label but it will not allow me add individual labels to the figures in the grid
I tried doing two figures side by side but it seems that can only work in a grid

The solution is to wrap each subfigure in a content block ([]). Then, a label is just part of the same content block and can attach to the figure:
 #grid(
  columns: 2,
  grid.cell([
    #figure(
      box("Pictures/PowerGeo.png", width: 90%),
      caption: [Arithmetic operations],
    )<fig:power-geo>
  ]),
  grid.cell([
    #figure(
      box("Pictures/PowerMath.png", width: 90%),
      caption: [Geometric operations],
    )<fig:power-math>
  ]),
)

Reference to @fig:power-geo


